# Simple program for running average in python yields index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, moving-average

No imports allowed. I am writing a program for a simple moving average but keep getting an error.

```
inp = 12345
lst = [int(x) for x in str(inp)]
x = range (len(lst))
for n in x:
    An =((lst[n]+ lst[n+1])/2)  
    print(An)
    n+=1
```

I keep getting:

```
1.5
2.5
3.5
4.5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ea7ffe0bd993> in <module>
      4 for n in x:
      5     while n <= 5:
----> 6         An =((lst[n]+ lst[n+1])/2)
      7         print(An)
      8         n+=1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know it is because of the `last[n+1]` term but no matter what `while` conditions I have tried I cannot get around this simple error

Comment: Have you tried `x = range (len(lst)-1)`?

Comment: The code in your trace doesn't match what was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `x = range(len(lst))` with `x = range(len(lst) - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Because here:

```
inp = 12345
lst = [int(x) for x in str(inp)]
x = range (len(lst))
for n in x:
    An =((lst[n]+ lst[n+1])/2)  
                        ^
    print(An)
    n+=1
```

you are adressing a value outside the length of x. To solve this you can just add: -1 to x:

```
inp = 12345
lst = [int(x) for x in str(inp)]
x = range (len(lst)-1)
                    ^
for n in x:
    An =((lst[n]+ lst[n+1])/2)  
    print(An)
    n+=1
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, That was the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark the answer as correct, so it is helpful to other people, too.